# Wiring a 4 speed blower motor to a single pole switch

Tags: electrical

I have a [Dayton 1XJY1A](https://www.grainger.com/product/DAYTON-Blower-with-Motor-11-in-Wheel-1XJY1) blower that I'd like to wire to a single pole, 3-way light switch, and plug into a wall outlet using a standard 14/3 power cable. The blower has 4 running speeds, but I really only need one of them for now until I can find a proper 5 position rotary switch for it.

The blower wiring diagram looks like this:

[image: blower wiring diagram]

And the switch looks like this:

[image: single pole 3-way switch]

I'm using a simple 14/3 power cable from hardware store, the kind with the wires pre-stripped for this sort of thing.

My first attempt at this was unsuccessful. I wired it as follows, but the blower wouldn't turn on in either switch position. Purple to cable white, black-1 to brass switch terminal-1, and cable black to brass switch terminal-2.

Nothing connected to black common screw on the switch. Green cable ground wire attached to green switch ground screw. The yellow, orange, and red blower wires were capped and unconnected.

Secondary question, the blower motor is grounded to the blower housing. Do I need to ground the housing to the switch ground screw?

Am I missing something here? This seems pretty straightforward, and yet the blower remains off.

Comment: I think you need the black screw and one of the brass screws, but need experts to be sure.

Comment: You are not mentioning the Neutral, permanently connected to the motor. (In your country probably the purple) in USA it is the White.

Comment: Frame challenge; These days it may be simplest to install a Motor Controller (the motor equivalent of a dimmer switch), wired to the Fan's high-speed connection. Not all motors are wild about running on motor controllers, admittedly. I've got one with smart-home features controlling one of the bathroom vents in my house.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a 3-way switch incorrectly.

A 3-way switch may be more familiar to you as an SPDT switch.  **Black terminal is common**.  Therefore the two brass terminals will never connect to each other in any switch configuration.

You should connect switch black to your power supply black, *one* of the switch brass screws to the speed wires of your preference, and the other switch brass screw to nothing.  (because you need to have an "off" position somewhere, right?).

I suppose you could connect the other brass screw to a different speed wire, but then the fan would be always running.

Oh, and two other things.  First, fans generally need to be setup on a switch so they start on "HIGH" first. On lower settings they may not get enough torque to be able to start.

Second, make sure you are doing enclosures, grounding and other safety details in a manner UL would be likely to approve.  No "science projects" with AC power; this stuff can kill you or start a fire.

*The normal way you use a 3-way*

[image]

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! I was confused about the internal connections of the switch. I had assumed the brass screws would be connected to each other in the on-position. Connecting a hot wire to a screw labelled common is a bit uncomfortable though, so I think I will get a true single pole switch instead. This is all going in a box, I just wanted to test the fan before assembling. Safety first! Also, thanks for the tip about starting fans at top speed, super helpful.

Comment: You're thinking of "common == ground (like in DC) == neutral (because we use neutral not ground in normal AC wiring". But it isn't that way. "common" in a US AC switch literally means "common to two other things", and it is called that on a 3-way switch because (as in Harper's diagram) the common might be "hot" or it might be "switched hot".

Answer (score 0):

Your motor needs two wires to run.

One is Power, the other is Neutral.

I would not use colors to know which one is which.

You must use a tool, like a phase tester to know for sure.

The 3 way switches are identical. However they function is different. One becomes the Inlet and the other the outlet. The inlet is the one with permanent Hot coming from circuit breaker. The outlet is the one connected to the motor.

Find and connect the Permanent Hot to bottom screw. The top two screws bring switched hot to the second 3 way switch. On the second 3 way the single screw is to be connected to the motor while the top two get wires from first switch.

The Neutral is NOT switched and goes directly to the motor.

[image: 3 way]

Answer (score 0):

To run at a single speed, connect Purple to the Neutral side of the AC, and put a simple switch between hot and the motor's wire appropriate for that speed (black for highest, red for lowest). Insulate the other speed control wires by putting tape or wire nuts over their ends, to prevent short circuits.

This is really all the fancy selection switch is doing, except that it lets you change which speed wire you want to use without having to disconnect and reconnect.

Answer (score -2):

to get all 4 motor speeds you need 4 switches.  Purple is the same as white for ground or neutral. Connect the purple to the white line that connects to the widest blade of an outlet plugh.  The round ground wire on the outlet plug will be connected to ground the switches to the fan.  One on off switch between from the power supply will turn the fan on/off. It connects to 3 way switch #1 (3W1)to supply power to the fan speed selection switches. Since there are 4 speeds we need a second set of 3 way switches to individually select one of the 4 speeds. Black or Red wires normally indicate a hot wire and white is a neutral or ground.  Connect a black wire from the first 3 way to 3way switch #2 line terminal. Fan wire black (highest speed) goes to one terminal and fan wire yellow (Med high) on your diagram goes to the other terminal of  3way switch #2.  Connect a red wire from 3 way switch #1 to the line terminal of 3way switch #3.  Connect the Orange fan wire (Med Low) to one terminal of 3way switch#3 and the fan red (low speed) to the other load terminal of 3 way switch #3. All of these switches should be in a box and grounded to the squirrel cage fan.  One switch is on/off. 3way Switch #1 is hi or low range. and 3 way switch #2 and 3 are high or low for a range selected by switch #2. I couldn't think of a wiring method for less switches.  If you can get by with only two speeds then you only need two switches for on/off and hi/low speed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Actually. two switches would allow off plus two speeds, if the second is SPDT to select the speed when on. A third could add a third speed, but it'd be an ugly solution.